# Building circuits with BuildCraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm making a large logic circuit with ProjectRed, and there are a lot of parts of the circuit that are repeated in a line, so I'd like to "copy and paste" a block several times. To do this, I've built the block I want to copy and I'm using the architect table and builder from BuildCraft. I surround the block I want to copy with land marks, put the architect table next to them, and produce a blueprint. However, when I put the blueprint into a powered Builder, the Builder immediately removes the blueprint from the blueprint slot and puts it in the inventory. Is this an issue with BuildCraft and ProjectRed not working together? If so, is there another way to do this? I'm using the FTB Inventors pack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like it's impossible with buildcraft. However, I did solve my problem by using ProjectRed's customisable IC gates to massively reduce the amount of space and copy/pasting required.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Buildcraft is not compatible with ProjectRed.

There was a convenient  article I found was on the [BuildCraft FAQ](https://www.mod-buildcraft.com/pages/faq.html), under the section ***What mods do the BuildCraft Builders support?***, which gave me this information:

[image]

In the second list, there is an item called RedLogic.  This mod is the replacement for PR2 which is why there is no support for for it on this list.

To sum up, you cannot use the BuildCraft Builder for ProjectRed specialty blocks.

Comment: So what options do I have? Is there a similar thing from another mod that does work with PR?

Comment: How many times do you want it pasted, if it's around 10 or less, you're better off building it over again, it will take less time than trying to find a solution.

Comment: I need it pasted at least 32 times, but don't worry I found my own solution.